# Git in Python and Spec Files

Tags: python, git, rpm, specifications

I am currently writing a Python script for use on Linux machines that will loop through a list of packages and update their rpm spec files on a repository to include a certain change. My difficulty is with actually getting the spec files (which are blobs?) from the git repository. Some guidance would be appreciated on how to do two things.

1. Get an rpm spec file given a package name from a git repository.
2. Put the updated spec file back (commit?)

Thanks

Comment: What is a "spec" file? I'm unsure of what you mean. If it's a file with a name, a checked out repository will have it.

Comment: A spec file is used when dealing with RPM repositories that store packages. It is just part of the package that would be stored in the repo.

Comment: Well then you should mention that and tag the question so. There's no mention of RPMs anywhere in your question.

Comment: I agree, I will add it to the tag, thank you.

Comment: Do you know the names of the spec files? If so, you can just edit them in the repo, git add and git commit -m them. Why bother with blobs and stuff?

Comment: Yes I would know the name of the spec file. It could be derived from the package name. I'm curious about the actual python code to do this. Please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of the file is `A/b/foo.spec` for package `A`, you would

```
  f = open ("repository/A/b/foo.spec")
  change_file(f)
  run_command(git add A/b/foo.spec)
  run_command(git commit -m "Changed spec file for package A")
```

Implement the change_file and run_command functions. The run_command functions should run their arugments inside the repository.

Comment: Is there anyway to open the file as a file object in Python? Changes aren't a simple insert or remove.

Comment: If you know the name of the file, you can simply say `open(file_name)`. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I've tried to write a skeleton for you. If there's still some confusion, please restate your question properly.

Comment: Sorry, we misunderstood each other. The way you're code looks to me it would be run on the local machine that contains the repo. How about if this isn't the case. I have very little experience with git and repo's. I just want to be able to do:
spec=open(path,'w')

Comment: Then run a command to make a local clone of the repository before you start doing this. The command would be `git clone path_to_remote_repo local_directory`. Once you get that, do all the work inside the local repository and then `git push` it back to the remote.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, sorry for my poor explanation of the problem. I will try this out.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing, what library is this assuming I'm including? gitpython?

Comment: No. You're using raw Python and using the standard subprocess module to execute the git commands.